# Convert Java 8 feature to Java 1.5

Tags: java-8, java-5

How do I convert the below mentioned piece of code in Java 1.5?

```
final List<String> filteredEntries = entries.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.toLowerCase().contains(getText().toLowerCase()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
searchResult.addAll(fitleredEntries)
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Use a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for (String e : entries) {
    if (e.toLowerCase().contains(getText().toLowerCase())) {
        searchResult.add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the fact that java 5 'old' approach is shorter and easier to read than fancy 'functional' approach ;)

Comment: Assuming that search uses `toLowerCase()` with meaning "ignoreCase", it will be better to use `equalsIgnoreCase` method available on `String` class. Could be slightly more performant (because we wouldn't need to convert full strings just to know they don't match anyway because first symbol is different) and easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski, functional approach solves slightly different problems than "old" approach. There's obviously nothing wrong with old style if it does its job. I frankly surprised how many questions there are asking "how do I rewrite this perfectly reasonable code into using streams".

Comment: @Mikhail Prokhorov: `equalsIgnoreCase` checks for a full match, which differs from the `contains` semantic. If you are heading for performance, you might prefer: `entries.stream() .filter(Pattern.compile(getText(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.LITERAL) .asPredicate()) .forEachOrdered(searchResult::add);`.

Comment: @Holger, yeah, I misread the question and answer (missed `contains` part). You are right, equalsIgnoreCase won't work there.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov `equalsIgnoreCase` also fails when faced with Unicode characters outside the basic multilingual plane i.e. code points above 64k.